# How to avoid ignore the next mediator using response mediator in WSO2 EI?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have a REST service that returns a json simple {message: "ok"}. When I use Respond Mediator this stop further processing of a message and send the message back to the client.

I need to send response to client, and then execute task asynchronously, but if I use  it ignores the next call to a sequence or an endpoint.

How can you respond synchronously (response to client) and then invoke a service, without response mediator ignore the next mediator?

thanks;

Comment: Did you tried to clone your message (using clone mediator), in one of the clone respond and the other one continue your processing ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for you response, I do not need to clone a message, only  respond to cliente and then follow asynchronously.

Comment: Is only send response to client and then execute a block async (Asynchronous), for example use send mediator and finish.

Comment: Yes It was the goal of the clone mediator usage in this case, you clone the message, send it back in one hand and in the other hand perform your processing asynchronously.

Comment: I'm going to try first running the clone mediator and then the response mediator. Thanks Nicolas.

Comment: Clone mediator not just clone message, it give new separate life to new message, total independent (async) from original.

Comment: I develop a simple api, but do not return a response. 
         <inSequence>                      
         <payloadFactory media-type="json">                        
            <format>{"message":"asyn test"}</format>                        
            <args/>                  
         </payloadFactory>                  
         <clone>                        
            <target sequence="logSequence"/>                  
         </clone>                  
         <respond/>            
      </inSequence>

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the challenge. effectively Clone mediator not just clone message, it give new separate life to new message.

```
 <api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="porticApiAsyn" context="/test">
<resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/asyn">
  <inSequence>
     <log>
        <property name="message" value="asyn"/>
     </log>
     <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>{"message":"asyn test"}</format>
        <args/>
     </payloadFactory>
     <clone continueParent="true" sequential="true">
        <target sequence="logSequence"/>
     </clone>
     <respond/>
  </inSequence>
```

In this case, the message is sent to logsequence, then the response mediator is executed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For your case you could even do the following

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="porticApiAsyn" context="/test">
<resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/asyn">
  <inSequence>
     <log>
        <property name="message" value="asyn"/>
     </log>
     <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>{"message":"asyn test"}</format>
        <args/>
     </payloadFactory>
     <clone continueParent="true" sequential="true">
        <target sequence="logSequence"/>
        <target>
          <sequence>
            <respond/>
          </sequence>
        </target>
     </clone>
  </inSequence>
```

I guess it should work as well and is maybe more readable

Comment: Thank Nicolas for you support. I will include this feature.